# how to mark as one asset an object with separated parts?

Tags: export, file-browser, asset, asset-browser

Can someone help me please?
I want to add one of my model to the blender's new asset browser (blender 3.0.0), but the model is made from multiple parts.
For example i have a katana that has a blade and a handle. And when i try to select both of them the assetbrowser mark them as two separated object.
I also tried to mark the collection where they are as asset, but its grayed out. Can someone help me out?
Thank you:)
(blender 3.0.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 From outliner, "instance to scene" collection -> collection instance created

2 "Mark as asset" that instance

Comment: When I drag and drop this asset into the scene, in another file, it seems to only do so as a linked object, as in, I cannot edit it and use the object in that file. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: @DangerCritter777 The way I know is to use `File > Append` and dive into a blend file then append the collection. Then u can edit it.

Comment: So blender do have this feature but not in asset browser. It seems like asset browser is still under development.

Comment: Same thing in File Browser. In file browser u cannot dive into a blend file. But `File > append` can.

Comment: Hope we can just drag and drop using asset browser or file browser. And it perform the same as `File > append`. Unfortunately it can't:(

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, Collections are not a supported type for the asset browser, (see the release notes [Asset Browser](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Asset_Browser) section for what is supported,) so you really only have two choices:

1. Treat each object separately and deal with the complexity that entails.
2. Merge all of the individual objects into a single object and deal with the complexity that entails.

In your case, I would join the blade and handle to make the katana object and then enter it as the asset.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and use the 2nd approach from [Marty Fouts' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245031/127890), but use geometry nodes for it. In case anyone needs this, here is my solution on how to merge the whole collection into a single object.

1. create a plane or cube
2. add geometry node modifier
3. add the "Collection Info" node and select the collection you want. I needed to select "Relative".
4. add the "Realize Instances" node. This was necessary so that my collection could be merged when applying the modifier.
5. connect the output "Geometry" from 3. to 4. and from 4. to "Group Output".
6. Apply the geometry node modifier. This prevents the entire collection from being loaded.

The steps from 3 to 5 can be seen in the following picture:
[image: Geometry node example]

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:
[https://brandonsdrawings.com/2022/01/18/collections-as-assets-hack/#:~:text=Clicking%20on%20a%20collection%20in,add%20to%20your%20asset%20library](https://brandonsdrawings.com/2022/01/18/collections-as-assets-hack/#:%7E:text=Clicking%20on%20a%20collection%20in,add%20to%20your%20asset%20library).

It works. It basically says make a collection. Press Shift+A in Layout, add an collection instance. Then you can go to your object list and mark it as asset. The whole thing becomes one object.

Answer (score 0):

On Blender 3.6.0 at least it is just possible to select the objects. Press M to do "Move to Group", create a new group and then mark the group as an asset.