Is making quads necessary when Intersecting objects?
I have always been a fanatic about making sure everything is made of quads but I am doing some archvis where the camera moves around the room (but objects remain stationary) and started wondering if I'm killing myself going through the trouble of cutting quads on objects that intersect that aren't going to be changing shape. A good example would be a window casing where the vertical and horizontal parts come together. I want to join the trim into a single object so I can library it and don't see why I would really need to go through the trouble of building quads out of every face that touch. I ran a simple render (animating with EEVEE) and didn't see any issues with shadows or faces warping.  
Close up of full unit
[

There isn't really a reason to have the objects be a single mesh to my knowledge. You want a single mesh when you are making stuff for 3D printing for example, bc it reduces the possible issues and overall geometry. Or if you want to give the impression that the whole thing as been covered in thick paint and you need a smooth connection.  But otherwise, for a normal render, if it already looks good like that you don't have to merge them. To begin with, in a real window, those would be separate parts

Yes, in a real window they would be separate parts but even if parented, you can't mark them as a single asset to pull out of a library later for another project, I have to join the parts as a single object, then mark as asset. The vertical sides come down and touch the window stool, an apron would be below that touching the bottom of the stool. I would have to cut a good number of loop cuts and cuts to make every intersection be only quads yet, if I'm not doing any flexing of the parts when the camera moves, I'm wondering if cutting all of those quads is even going to matter.

Why should quads be necessary ? Especially if you don't use modifiers such as Bevel, Subdiv Surface, ... You can have tris, quads, or n-gons. About multiple objects as assets : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245019/how-to-mark-as-one-asset-an-object-with-separated-parts

That's exactly what I was wondering. On a character I have to contend with a lot of flexing of curved faces so I keep everything quads, all these archvis parts are in straight lines and don't need to bend or flex in an animation.

@Cornivius yes, they would be separate parts, but if you painted it after being assembled, the paint would connect the surfaces. Path11, what Cornivius really meant by not merging is that you can have separate "hulls" (mesh islands, selected separately with "L" key) within one object. If you sell this as an asset, clients may appreciate quad topology, because some of them will want to deform or bevel the window. So as usual: it depends. When it comes to bevel, subdivision, you only really need 1 or 2 buffer loops of quads between flat surfaces.

I like everything quads too but, in this case, I have no intent on selling the asset, just use in my own production (I am creating a remodel web series). I would normally be all about making it quads, this is the first time I have ever considered not making everything quads but, I'm also considering not processing unnecessary quads to keep rendering quicker for animation. I could easily double the number of faces on the object by adding all the loops and cuts to make quads but, I have to consider that I would then be multiplying it times every window. I'm wondering if that would be necessary.

If you're fine with the shading as it is, then don't bother and move on. :)

No, it is not.
If you don't have a reason to do something you should not do it. If you are modelling objects that are separate objects in real world there is absolutely no need to join them or connect their topology. Actually it would be more realistic to keep them separate as there are often small gaps between them that might be still visible from further away. They might collect dust or dirt or simply have a shadow and be visible as lines. So this is not only a complete waste of time, but also has a negative effect on the realism of your models. It's not even unnecessary, you should actually not do it.

There is a reason, see added pics. I'm rendering with EEVEE, the projects are for entertainment/education web series incorporating video and animation. They will show destruction/reconstruction of homes and don't need photo realism, I have video for that. Grouping as one unit lets me change size by editing X-ray, grouping vertical or horizontal verts for resizing, which avoids the distortion of scaling. When there 20-40 windows in a building that need to be created, five parts being moved and resized is time consuming. They don't change size during animation, wondering if it will blow up.

One other thing, just in case I need it, I took the top three casing parts joined, the window stool, and the apron and made them vertex groups then grouped the entire thing as a single object. I did that in case I wanted to change the molding type for any of those by selecting the vertex group and deleting, then adding the new molding and grouping again. Speed is the critical part, if this takes off like I am having indications of, I need to roll out animations and/or getting other archvis artists to do sections. Providing assets like a window moulding grouped to them helps their process

You don't need 5 objects per window. They can be parented or you can join multiple meshes to one object.

I don't see how model's topology or number of mesh islands can affect animation functionality, unless you want to do soft deformations...

To the second comment - hit L while hovering over some topology to quickly select linked.

Martynas Žiemys - That's what I was thinking too, they aren't deforming so why am I killing myself cutting quads all over it? Having only dealt with quads (I've been a nut for them), i was wondering if there were any hidden issues before I spent a day laying in the new window trims. So far, seems nobody finds issue. The problem with parenting is, you can't library the group, Blender will only library one of the objects so, I think I got around that by creating vertex groups within the object. As I get busy, I'd like to pass off assets to other artists I can hire to help with new projects.

There are no issues with n-gons if there are no issues with n-gons. You avoid them because they sometimes have issues, if they don't they don't, that's fine. Everybody uses n-gons sometimes... But I have no idea, why you want to connect the topology at all if they are separate parts in reality. That makes no sense to me. I mean are you sure you have a good reason to connect them? You sure there is no proper way to do what you want? I cannot imagine a situation where separate parts of a mesh would become a problem in non deforming objects especially if they are separate in reality..

This seems like an XY problem. You might have a chance to save yourself some headache if you shared the wider context of what you are trying to do in detail. Maybe the higher lever goal is achieved some other way than what you are trying to do.

Sure, very good reason. You have thirty windows, several sizes, you can copy the group of five parts to a new window then, you have to resize each parts length and connect them. With a single group, I can move the object to the new window, block the horizontal and vertical vertices like shown, resize width and height in two moves then on to the next window. You're there all day moving and sizing five parts. Now, when I get busier, I need other artists and want to make their workflow smooth.

No that doesn't work like that. You can do the same with whatever object you want. Ask another question about that maybe. Yuo can use hook modifiers (ctrl+H with verts selected) amd then duplicate linked the same object also saving memory.

It works fine, while we were conversing I laid in 43 window and door casings, different sizes, all with the same casing (one door one window), two quick vert adjustments to size  each, and no modifiers. look at the pics again, real simple to adjust.

Here have a look. A bit more complex setup, but if you have loads of them that might be easier: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320582/how-duplicate-a-lot-of-windows-all-in-different-sizes-when-the-frames-are-the-sa/320583#320583

That's another way but, I think you're getting wrapped up in an older way. My windows are separate from my trim and can be resized the same way quickly BUT, the problem both of our methods have is the horizontal mullions don't adjust automatically, they have to be parametric to do that. Notice when you change your window height the cross mullion doesn't adjust, same with mine and we would both have to manually adjust everything. So, Geometry Nodes can do that. I haven't dug deep into GeoNodes but I will because there is one place that would REALLy come in handy, and that is cabinet doors.

It's easy to hook it to the top empty and adjust the strength of it by any amount you want, so it moves in any way "automatically". In any case, no topology needs to be connected if it's not connected in real life. I don't see why it would need to be even in the case you describe. Not sure I am getting what this all about at all.
