How to duplicate a lot of windows all in different sizes when the frames are the same?
So let's say I have a model of a window and I have a lot of holes in my walls dedicated for windows that are all different sizes but exact same type as my first window and I want to copy it and scale it to correct sizes, but I want to avoid going to edit mode and moving vertices of each one (because I have like 43 of them or something) and I want to do it quickly and efficiently.
What can I do?


This comes from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320504/is-making-quads-necessary-when-intersecting-objects

I can use Hook modifiers and duplicate the window together with hook objects parented to it, then just snap the hooks into places.
I probably first want to make sure I can snap the whole window to some point, so I'll just move it's origin to some corner of my first hole in the wall:

Then I can snap an empty to one of the edges of the hole, select my window, go to edit mode, select that side  Ctrl  +  Click   on that empty to select it from edit mode and hit  Ctrl  +  H  to hook it to that selected empty. I also want to parent that empty to my window( Ctrl  +  P ):

Now when I move my window it moves normally and moves the empty with itself, but when I move the empty, it moves the side of the window:

I also just so happen to have geometry in the middle, so I can hook it to the same empty and just adjust the modifier to be half as strong:

I can repeat the same process for the top and any other parts I want to easily snap not forgetting to parent all the empties to my window. Now I have an adjustable window. I can use  Alt  +  D  duplicate linked to also only have the geometry of my 43 windows only saved once in the file(And it might also have some benefits when rendering).
Now I can start duplicating them. I just also need to remember to select children by hitting
 Shift  +  ]  so the empties are also duplicated and I just snap the empties while holding  Ctrl  down:


Interesting use of the hook modifier, and linked duplicates to keep the geometry definition count low. I hope the geometry nodes gizmos that are in the works will help simplify this process

I think it's physically faster to setup because of Ctrl + H hotkey and because hook modifiers can automatically take care of offsets. It will probably take longer to set up Geometry Nodes. But who knows. Geometry Nodes Gizmos sound exciting.

FWIW https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes-gizmos-feedback/32073

Is it going to support snapping though?

I hope so, it would be a shame if it didn't.
